# Create a Navigation Menu in MvvmCross WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, mvvmcross

It's almost a week I've been trying to find a way to implement a Navigation Menu in WPF using MvvmCross 7 with no success. I had no luck even doing a research with similar solution, my impression is MvvmCross is mainly used with Xamarin and that WPF is not used at all. At this point I'm suffering a deep loneliness.

The idea is simple: show a view inside a main view in order to change it dinamically. The main view is the menu with all the buttons and the child view is the content of the button pressed.
I' ve been able to achive it using this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5275552/WPF-Compact-Navigation-Menu but I won't feel good until a find the correct way using MvvmCross.

Can you give me a starting point or some hints?